# C# - Get Ajax data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want to send data though Ajax to a C# file, but when I check the received data, It gives me null. Is there someting wrong with my code?

**Javascript file**

```
 $(".save").click(function () {
    var ss = "Helloo!";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Notes/save.cshtml",
        global: true,
        data: {fofo: ss},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
 },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("There was a problem with the server. Try refreshing the page.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**C# File which receives the data (save.cshtml)**

```
@{
  var s = Request.Form["fofo"];
 var result = "";
    var userData = s;

    var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/Notes/lolo.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(@dataFile, s);
    result = "Information saved.";
}
 @if(result != ""){
    <p>Result: @result, @s</p>

}
```

Comment: is this a form? if so need to prevent default submit if `.save` is type=submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending a `response` back to your `AJAX` function.  Not only that what you're doing isn't standard `MVC`.  You should be hitting a `Controller` which saves the data in the file at the server side and then send the result back using a `JsonResult`.

For example:

```
public JsonResult SaveNotes()
{
    // Code to save file here

    // Return the response 
    return Json({NotesSaved = true});
}
```

Then in your `JavaScript AJAX` success object you will then have the `NotesSaved` object set to true.

Note: You should also change your `URL` parameter in the `AJAX` command to something like:

```
 url: '@Url.Action("SaveNotes")'
```

Comment: last part won't work if using external js file though

Comment: @charlietfl - that is true.. He will have to use a static string or pass it via a global object.  I'll update my answer to include this. I think the main point is that it should be going through a `Controller`.